# Stomped on a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS" for a block handler

Tags: ios, crash, objective-c-blocks

I have production code which I see that it crashes once in a while with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` on the block handler. I could for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code. I have tried to reproduce this and could not in my controlled environment. Here is the stripped out and cleaned up code :

**Code Snippet :**

```
typedef void (^TestCallBackHandler)(NSString* location, NSError* error);

@interface _TestClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) TestCallBackHandler handler;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSTimer *endTimer;

- (void)fireOneOff:(TestCallBackHandler)handler;

@end

@implementation _TestClass

- (void)fireOneOff:(TestCallBackHandler)handler
{
    _handler = handler;

    NSLog(@"** New %p %@ Incoming %p, %@ Ours %p %@",self,self,handler, handler, _handler, _handler);
    _endTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(_stop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%@ Dealloced",self);
    _handler = nil;
}

- (void)_stop
{
    NSLog(@"** Stopping ? %@",self);
    if (_handler)
        _handler([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@",[NSDate date]], nil);
}

@end
```

The calling code in my class is defined as :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)_TestClass *testClassInstance;
```

and called like this :

```
- (void)startTestClass {
    _testClassInstance =  [[_TestClass alloc] init];
    [_testClassInstance fireOneOff:^(NSString *newString, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Got new String! %@",newString);
    _testClassInstance = nil;
}];
}
```

Few things to note :

- The startTestClass can be called multiple times
- The app wakes up in the background and this can be created.

Any pointers, help highly appreciated.. I just cant put a finger in this code and say that is what is wrong. Please help!

Comment: where does it crash?

Comment: are you using ARC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two hints which occur a little bit strange to me:

First: why are you setting the object to nil in it's own block.

```
- (void)startTestClass {
        _testClassInstance =  [[_TestClass alloc] init];
        [_testClassInstance fireOneOff:^(NSString *newString, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Got new String! %@",newString);
        _testClassInstance = nil;
    }];
}
```

Second your object may be released already and the NSTimer is trying to execute a method on a release object

```
- (void)fireOneOff:(TestCallBackHandler)handler
{
    _handler = handler;

    NSLog(@"** New %p %@ Incoming %p, %@ Ours %p %@",self,self,handler, handler, _handler, _handler);
    _endTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(_stop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

I also dont get what the code does exactly and why. I believe there would be an easier and better maintainable solution for what you are achieving in this class.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. What I am trying to do is to get one location from CoreLocation in my fireOneOff code. But I do see that setting the object to nil in the block definitely does not look right. I will make sure my timers are cleared explicitly.

Comment: "Second your object may be released already and the NSTimer is trying to execute a method on a release object" `+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]` retains the target.

Comment: "First: why are you setting the object to nil in it's own block." There is nothing wrong here with setting another object's instance variable to `nil`. In fact here it breaks a retain cycle. Even if it causes deallocation of the `TestClass` object (which it shouldn't because `NSTimer` should still be holding on to it at this point), that's not a problem because nothing is run after executing the `_handler` in `-_stop`.

Comment: If you are using core location I would make a singleton which implements the delegate methods of CLLocationManager and holds one of those manager as a variable. If you get a callback from your manager you can handle the location. No timers needed, no blocks needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more information about EXC_BAD_ACCESS, then you can turn of NSZombies. In Xcode go to **Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme** and set checked **Enable Zombie Objects**.

Comment: this is happening in the wild.. not when I am testing it, so this won't help.